# How to use html file upload method for google site verification for a flask app

Tags: python-3.x, flask, heroku, google-search-console

The pretty straight forward way to do this is to upload the `google-provided.html` file to the root folder of your app on the server. But how to do it for a flask application?

For example, I have a flask app running on heroku and I want to do the site verification for my app using **html file upload** method(though alternative methods are available). I tried uploading the `google-provided.html` in the templates folder. Verification failed!

I have searched the internet but found no relevant answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask uses directory structure that contains `/templates` folder where our html files should be present.

To access any `.html` file, there needs to be a route and a view defined. So, in order to make your site verification process success, in addition to placing the `google-provided.html` file in templates folder, you need to define a route and a view so that the google bot which tries to access the `google-provided.html` file can find it.

The route should be `/google-provided.html` and view should render the template `google-provided.html` because the google bot looks at `app.yourdomain.com/google-provided.html` for the `google-provided.html` file in your app.

Simply put, it should look something like this:

```
@app.route("/google-provided.html")
def google_site_verf():
    return render_template("google-provided.html")
```

I encountered this issue today and found the solution myself. Hence thought of sharing this here so that it could help someone.

Feel free to drop suggestions/improvements. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Everything mentioned in the above answer is correct. But, just make sure that you don't rename the file given from google search console. Use the same name as it is.